# What is the cause of the sed error?

Tags: text-processing, sed

In my grunt file I have the command like this

```
"sed -i index 's/API_CONTEXT_URI/http:\\/\\/localhost:5557/g' www/index.js"
```

This is not a file I have written; this has to come to me as a maintenance project. So I don't understand that line properly. It is supposed to replace the string API_CONTEXT_URI with the URL provided in `index.js`. The error is

```
can't read s/API_CONTEXT_URI/http://localhost:5557/g: No such file or directory
```

According to what I interpret, `sed` could not find `index.js`. But there is an `index.js` in the `www` folder. I have tried changing `\\/` to `\` to escape `/`, but still it would not work. Can you guys help me in where to look at? I am suspicious about the `-i` and `index` in the command.

Comment: remove the word `index`. it is being taken as the command to run.

Comment: What about looking at the man page if you don't understand a certain flag? eg. http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/sed1.html

Comment: Why is it all in double quotes ?

Comment: `sed` interprets `index` after `-i` (because of the space between them) as a command and everything that follows as input files. In fact some seds will even edit your `index.js` in-place and prepend a line containing `ndex` to each line in your file because `i` in `index` is interpreted as a sed command (which means insert the text that follows before addressed lines but there are no addressed lines so it does it for every line).

Comment: Because it was like this command: "sed ---- " in grunt @User112638726

Comment: A bit of general advice: whenever you see the phrase `No such file or directory` (or any of the other error messages listed [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html); e.g., `File exists`, `Permission denied`, `Filename too long`, `Is a directory`, `Not a directory`, etc.) following a `: ` (colon + space), you should consider the possibility that the system is trying to interpret the string to the left of *that* as a filename, no matter how obvious it is to you (or any other reasonable human being) that it is not a filename.

Answer (score 5):

1. there is a missing `-e` before s/foo/bar/ (*)
2. there is a confusion, are you (the script)  editing `index` or `www/index.js` ?

   if `index` is a template file (with API_CONTEXT_URL) to be used to produce `www/index.js`, I would suggest

   ```
   sed -e s,API_CONTEXT_URL,http://localhost:5557,g index > www/index.js
   ```

   note that you can use any chat a separator between substitute, I use comma (,) to avoid to much escaping.

   If file to be edited is `www/index.js`, use

   ```
   sed -i -e s,API_CONTEXT_URL,http://localhost:5557,g  www/index.js
   ```

   where

   - `-i` flag tell sed to edit file in place.

EDIT:
thanks to User112638726 and don_crissti, error is <s>pretty obvious</s>

```
    sed -i index 's/API_CONTEXT_URI/http:\\/\\/localhost:5557/g' www/index.js
```

will be interpreted by sed as

- `-i` edit in place,
- `index` that is `i` (insert) `ndex`,
- to the two files :
- `'s/API_CONTEXT_URI/http:\\/\\/localhost:5557/g'` and `www/index.js`.

I assume, there is no file called `s/API_CONTEXT_URI/http:\\/\\/localhost:5557/g`, that is a file `g` in directory `http:\\/\\/localhost:5557` in directory `API_CONTEXT_URI` in directory `s` in current directory.

---

I always use `-e command`, just in case I need to put two, I discover sed can handle (nowdays) a single command, I am not sure it was the case in old times.

Comment: The file after the -i is a backup file that is created when the original is edited.

Comment: so you mean to say "index" needs to be removed and -e should be put? and there is no need to escape the / with double quotes?

Comment: No. _1._ `-e` is superfluous in this case as you're only using a single `sed` _expression_. _2._   @User112638726's comment is misleading. The `index` after `-i` is supposed to be the suffix of the backup file, indeed but if only there was no space in-between. So `-i index` is interpreted as _edit the file in place (make no backup) using the expression_ `index`  - see my comment under the question... So the cause of this problem is that single space character. It has to be removed, e.g. `-iindex` or `-i.index` etc... for the command to work.

Comment: @don_crissti Yep, should have been clearer.